# Angular code not seeing controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I'm somewhat new to Angular so this may be something obvious I'm missing but...

I have a page with three main sections: top,middle, bottom.  Nav buttons on the top make calls to JS functions that use $.ajax() to find pages and then populate the middle section. However, the angular references in the included file aren't working. It's like it can't see the controller. The ng-controller is on the body tag, but I also put it on the div in the included file in case that was the cause, but to no avail.

Does the angular code not know about the controller since it was loaded after the main page?

How can I get the angular code in the included file to work?  I'm specifically using ng-click and ng-controller, but I also tried just outputting a variable from inside the controller and it simply outputs {{nav.sidelink}} to the screen.

app.js:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('vetSite', []);

app.controller('NavController', function(){

    var subtab = 1;
    var sidelink = 1;

    this.setTab = function(st){
        this.tab = st;
    }

    this.isSet = function(ct){
        return this.tab === ct;
    }

    this.setSubTab = function(st){
        this.subtab = st;
    }

    this.isSetSub = function(ct){
        return this.subtab === ct;
    }

    this.setSideLink = function(sl){
        this.sidelink = sl;
    }

    this.isSetSideLink = function(cl){
        return this.sidelink === cl;
    }

});

})();
```

HTML of included file:

```
<div id="subcontent">
    <div ng-show="nav.isSetSideLink(1)">
    Prairie has quality machines in our laboratory that can give us blood cell counts, electrolytes, and blood chemistry to check internal organs.  This enables us to diagnose and treat patients rapidly, and to monitor response to treatment without waiting 24 hours for the bloodwork to come back from an outside laboratory.  Having this information can make a huge difference in our success. 
    </div>

    <div ng-show="nav.isSetSideLink(2)">
    Being able to evaluate joint fluid for infection allows us to make a diagnosis and start treatment rapidly, increasing the chances of a positive outcome.
    </div>

    <div ng-show="nav.isSetSideLink(3)">
    Real time evaluation of abdominal fluid can help with the diagnosis of colic.  Increases in white blood cells and changes in abdominal fluid  chemistries can indicate that the gut is becoming damaged.  Getting these horses to colic surgery more quickly can result in a better outcome.
    </div>

    <div ng-show="nav.isSetSideLink(4)">
     Running cultures in house enables us to know what type of bacteria is involved in an infection within 24-48 hours of an examination and can help direct treatment.  Obtaining an antibiotic sensitivity for that bacteria rapidly improves the chances for a quick, full recovery.  Sending cultures to an outside laboratory delays this information 36-48 hours.  
    </div>

</div>

<div id="subsidenav">
    <div class="side_subnavbutton" ng-class="{ side_navbutton_selected:nav.isSetSideLink(1) }"><a href ng-click="nav.setSideLink(1);">In-House Blood Analysis</a></div>

    <div class="side_subnavbutton" ng-class="{ side_navbutton_selected:nav.isSetSideLink(2) }"><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="nav.setSideLink(2);">In-House Joint Fluid Analysis</a></div>

    <div class="side_subnavbutton" ng-class="{ side_navbutton_selected:nav.isSetSideLink(3) }"><a href ng-click="nav.setSideLink(3);">In-House Abdominal Fluid Analysis</a></div>

    <div class="side_subnavbutton" ng-class="{ side_navbutton_selected:nav.isSetSideLink(4) }"><a href ng-click="nav.setSideLink(4);">In-House Cultures</a></div>
</div>
```

It's totally ignoring all references to nav. All four paragraphs are showing up, and none of the links are changing class (despite nav.sidelink being initialized)

How do I make it see the controller?

Thanks.

EDIT: Some potentially important information:

here is the originally loaded page:

```
<html ng-app="vetSite">

<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.2" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.2" src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script language="javascript1.2" src="/js/divs.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body ng-controller = "NavController as nav">

<div id="top_area">
<div id="header">
    <img src="/images/headerlogo.gif" align="left" />
    <img src = "/images/mastheads/fronthall_clearMH.jpg" align="right" />   <br clear="all"/>

    <div>
        <div class="buttondiv" style="left:50%;" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(1) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('home');" ng-click="nav.setTab(1);">HOME</a></div>
        <div class="buttondiv" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(2) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('staff');" ng-click="nav.setTab(2);">STAFF</a></div>
        <div class="buttondiv" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(3) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('services');" ng-click="nav.setTab(3); nav.setSubTab(1);">SERVICES</a></div>
        <div class="buttondiv" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(4) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('facility');" ng-click="nav.setTab(4); nav.setSubTab(1);">FACILITY</a></div>
        <div class="buttondiv" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(5) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('location');" ng-click="nav.setTab(5);">LOCATION</a></div>
        <div class="buttondiv" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(6) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('contact');" ng-click="nav.setTab(6);">CONTACT</a></div>
        <div class="buttondiv" ng-class="{ buttondiv_selected:nav.isSet(7) }"><a href="javascript:load_content('job');" ng-click="nav.setTab(7);">CAREER</a></div>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <br clear="all"/>

    <div id="separatordiv">&nbsp;</div>     

</div>
</div>

<div id="middle_area">

<br clear="all" />

<div id="subnav" ng-show="nav.isSet(3);" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(1) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('medicine');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(1);">Sports<br/>Medicine</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(2) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('surgery');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(2);">Surgery</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(3) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('imaging');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(3);">Diagnostic<br/>Imaging</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(4) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('labserv');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(4);">Laboratory<br/>Services</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(5) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('rep');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(5);">Reproduction</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(6) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('dent');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(6);">Dentistry</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(7) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('comp');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(7);">Complementary<br/>Medicine</a></div>  

<br/>
<br clear="all" />
</div>

<div id="subnav" ng-show="nav.isSet(4);" style="margin-left: 20px;">
<div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(1) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('lab');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(1);">Laboratory</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(2) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('pharm');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(2);">Pharmacy</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(3) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('hosp');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(3);">Hospital</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(4) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('exam');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(4);">Exam<br/>Room</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(5) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('surgeryroom');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(5);">Surgery<br/>Room</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(6) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('arenain');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(6);">Indoor<br/>Arena</a></div><div class="subbuttondiv" ng-class="{ subbuttondiv_selected:nav.isSetSub(7) }"><a href="javascript:load_subcontent('arenaout');" ng-click="nav.setSubTab(7);">Outdoor<br/>Arena</a></div>  

<br/>
<br clear="all" />
</div>

<div id="content">

(original content ofmain page)
<br clear="all" />

</div>
</div>

<div id="bottom_area">
<div id="separatordiv">&nbsp;</div>     
<div id="footer">
<br/>
</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything you see here works. It's when I click on one of those subnav items (that only show up when I click certain tabs) and the SUB page of HTML content loads, that the Angular in there doesn't work.

Comment: Need to see more code. Is Angular loading? Where are your `ng-app` and `ng-controller` attributes?

Comment: NavController in view?

Comment: I added code and some more explanation.

Comment: I think you need to add controller to the scope. Add this `return $scope.NavController = this;` at the end of the controller declaration

Comment: Nope. Didn't help and it resulted it those subnavs not remaining hidden until I clicked the appropriate nav item.

Comment: Also, I think you need to pass `$scope` to the function declaration - as in `app.controller('NavController', function($scope){...}`

Comment: add `$scope` as a parameter to your controller and also define these methods on the `$scope`.

Comment: idursun - I'm not sure I follow

Comment: Hmm, on all the top nav and subnav items, it's working fine without the quotes.

Comment: weird... that's not it then... but I thought you said it did not work so now you say it's working fine (even w/o quotes) - I am missing what the real issue is then...

Comment: The top nav and even the first level of subnav work.  The next level, that is loaded in via ajax, based off of a nav button click, isn't recognizing the controller.

Comment: do you mean this ? `<a href="javascript:load_content('staff');" ng-click="nav.setTab(2);">` -> I would change it to `<a href="#" ng-click="load_content('staff');nav.setTab(2);">` (and put the `load_content(...)` function into the controller

Comment: Nope. That part works fine.  Any content loaded by load_content, or load_subcontent, doesn't even seem to see Angular at all.

I just tested something else out and it's not just the controller. It simply doesn't realize it's Angular in the loaded files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68002/discussion-between-ochi-and-reverend-dovie).

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a javascript function that is not related to your controller in order to load your sub content? And how is it doing that? Where is this subcontent coming from? Are you making an http request and getting back a string that is html that you inject into the page? If that is the case you will need to $compile that so that angular knows about it

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry. I figured this out eventually and it had to do with $compile.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that I needed to recompile the page once I reloaded the new code to make Angular see it as not just text.

Thanks, all for your suggestions.